# Facebook Commenting

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I am displaying fb comments on my website using following script

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId={here is my app id}";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Its working perfect, but issue is coming while commenting, there is line below comment box

```
Your comment may also appear on "Page 1" Facebook Page.
```

I want my this should show "Page 2" which is another page of mine, and I am admin of both pages.
Is there any way I can associate this commenting app with my other facebook page. I created few other apps too but all showing same page.

Comment: Are you talking about Comment Mirroring? That’s a setting you make via the moderation dashboard, according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I did it.. and change settings for comment mirroring to required page.. but still it is showing old page.. I checked in different browsers also to see if its a cacheing issue.. but no luck